# How should I process nested data structures (e.g. JSON, XML, Parquet) with Dask?

Tags: json, xml, pandas, dask, parquet

We often work with scientific datasets distributed as small (<10G compressed), individual, but complex files (xml/json/parquet). UniProt is one example, and [here is a schema for it](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/related-sciences/platform-pipe/blob/master/notebooks/analysis/uniprot.ipynb#schema).

We typically process data like this using Spark since it is supported well. I wanted to see though what might exist for doing work like this with the Dataframe or Bag APIs. A few specific questions I had are:

Does anything exist for this other than writing custom python functions for `Bag.map` or `Dataframe/Series.apply`?
Given any dataset compatible with Parquet, are there any secondary ecosystems of more generic (possibly JIT compiled) functions for at least doing simple things like querying individual fields along an xml/json path?
Has anybody done work to efficiently infer a nested schema from xml/json? Even if that schema was an object that Dask/Pandas can’t use, simply knowing it would be helpful for figuring out how to write functions for something like `Bag.map`. I know there are a ton of Python json schema inference libraries, but none of them look to be compiled or otherwise built for performance when applied to thousands or millions of individual json objects.

Comment: I believe Martin Durant is writing an answer to this question ([discussion here](https://github.com/scikit-hep/awkward-1.0/issues/303)) so I won't steal his thunder. However, to avoid losing this thread, we think [Awkward Array](https://awkward-array.org/what-is-awkward.html) is a good solution to exactly what you're asking for. There are some missing pieces (conversion from Parquet, a write-up of how to use it in Numba, and Dask integration), but these are conveniences on top of a core that already does what you want.